# rosrun rviz and X Window

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All,

I recently received a Turtlebot to test out. I have tested it using a set of different simple examples such as dashboard and teleop. The robot works very well.

The next experiment will be to test Turtlebot navigation. After several experiments, I have found that, it was very difficult to do map building and navigation without using a workstation. Thus, I have acquired a workstation that runs Win7 and soon after that two programs namely Putty SSH client and Xming ver 6.9.0.31(X-window) are installed. I have tested the communication between these programs via turtlebot using the turtlebot_dashboard program and it works very well. All GUIs are displayed very nicely from Turtlebot server to the workstation using Xming/X-window.

However, after the following command is executed from the workstation, the Xming seems to be hanged or crashed and I have to terminate it with no luck:

rosrun rviz rviz -d 'rospack find turtlebot_navigation` /nav_rviz.vcg.

Thus, do you have any idea how to overcome this issue?

best wishes
Azizi.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44840/rosrun-rviz-and-x-window/) by [Azizisya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3286/azizisya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-01

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rviz needs OpenGL which doesn't work via X forwarding. I suggest you install Ubuntu on your workstation and run rviz locally. You could also try to use VirtualBox but rviz might not work there either.

You can install Ubuntu in parallel to your Windows installation.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for the answer. I thing, it would be much more reliable to install Ubuntu/ROS on the workstation.

---

Originally posted by [Azizisya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3286/azizisya/) with karma: 1 on 2012-10-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-10-03**:
Please do not create answers for discussing things. This is not a forum. Instead, please either edit your original post or use the comment functionality